# How to check If I am currently on home screen

Tags: android

Is this possible to check if currently my app is in background and home screen is launched

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (apps.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equals("com.android.launcher")
```

this somehow solved my problem only for default home

Comment: Good answer, but please also mention what is "apps" for complete answer.

Comment: @Rony: I would certainly like to know what "apps" is :-D

Comment: Sorry: apps is result of "mActivityManager.getRunningTasks()"

Answer (score 7):

There is no API to know whether the home screen is showing. However you can know when your app is sent to the background using the various Activity lifecycle callbacks (onStop, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this function,

```
public boolean isUserIsOnHomeScreen() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {
        if(process.pkgList[0].equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.launcher")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }           
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but this breaks down if the user has a third-party launcher in use.

Answer (score 1):

Wether use ***onPause/onStop*** and ***onResume*** methods for activity purposes,
or make advantage with an own implemented service for backround-processing (based on time-delays or messages/receivers).