# listen shake event when I am @ home screen in android

Tags: android, shake

I implemented shake event form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it).

1. But how can I listen shake event in home screen?
2. Is there any broadcast receiver or I have to create service for listen shake event?

I found [How to check If I am currently on home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062405/how-to-check-if-i-am-currently-on-home-screen) to get homescreen focued but for default only.
If I have custom home launcher then How can I recognize that launcher.
Is Manifest is having any identification for launcher application???

Help is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `Service` that listens for the shake event.

Comment: How can I identify home screen is focused?.. (For custom home launcher)

Comment: Can I check application is launcer application by reading menifest?